# How do you verify that a request was made with axios-mock-adapter?

Tags: unit-testing, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I am using https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter

I would like to know how can I verify that an endpoint was actually called by the system under test.

In this example:

```js
var axios = require('axios');
var MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');

// This sets the mock adapter on the default instance
var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

// Mock any GET request to /users
// arguments for reply are (status, data, headers)
mock.onGet('/users').reply(200, {
  users: [
    { id: 1, name: 'John Smith' }
  ]
});
```

How could I tell if a get on '/users' was called?

I am looking for something similar to what you can do in Jest:

```js
expect(mockFunc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

I realise I can use some custom logic when using a function to reply, and setting a local variable indicating if the request has been made. I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Note: This answer is now outdated, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66564315/2532489) by Laszlo Sarvold instead.**

---

axios-mock-adapter does not appear to have this functionality built in to it, however if you are using jest, you can use jest.spyOn.

For your example above

```js
let spy = jest.spyOn(axios, "get");
//run http request here
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Note: depending on what you are using, you may have to wrap your expect statement in setTimeout(function, 0) for it to work properly

Comment: Is there a way to spy on particular URL? I have multiple gets in one function and I want to verify each of them.

Comment: It is possible to change toHaveBeenCalled into toHaveBeenCalledWith. eg.: expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/users');

Comment: Yep that's exactly how I would do it. Note that if you were doing a post instead of a get, you'd also have the payload parameter. In this case if you don't care about verifying the payload data that was sent you could do expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/users', expect.anything()); to just verify the address

Comment: It workes, but when i run second test, the toHaveCalledTimes returns 2, somehow its not clearning the old call.

Comment: @SarmadShah Try running jest.clearAllMocks() after each test

Answer (score 18):

As per https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter there is an out of the box functionality for verifying request calls:

```js
expect(mock.history.post.length).toBe(1); // times called
expect(mock.history.post[0].data).toBe(JSON.stringify({ foo: "bar" })); // posted object
```

Comment: The bottom of the readme file has the section referred to in this correct answer: https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter#history

Comment: Remember to call mock.reset() after each test if you take this approach and mock isn't local to the test. Otherwise, mock.history.post[0] may be a mock call you made in a previous test.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to do

```js
//OP's Code
var axios = require('axios');
var MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');

// This sets the mock adapter on the default instance
var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

// Mock any GET request to /users
// arguments for reply are (status, data, headers)
mock.onGet('/users').reply(200, {
  users: [
    { id: 1, name: 'John Smith' }
  ]
});

const spy = jest.spyOn(mock, 'onGet');

//function call here

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/users')
```

Essentially since the Mock "intercepts" axios calls you can't test for an axios.get call.. because it never actually happens. But the mock.onGet function does get executed and you can verify what route was used to do it as well.

Trying to spy on axios when you're mocking it will get you an error looking like this

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: "/users"

Number of calls: 0
```

Cheers.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: This is mistaken. You are just testing that `onGet` is being called with `/users`, which is obviously true, you are doing it in your test code (`mock.onGet('/users')`). You are _not_ testing that any requests are being made, just that the mock is being set up.