# Verify request with axios-mock-adapter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I made the following test using MockAdapter from `axios-mock-adapter`.   However I'm trying to assert that the get function has effectively been called so I created a spy. 
For some reason it doesn't seem to work and I get:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Here's my test:

```
it('gets publications', async() => {

    let spy = jest.spyOn(axios, "get");
    var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    mock.onGet(PUBLICATIONS_PATH + '/publications').reply(200, 
        {
            answer: {
                publications: [ "pub1", "pub2", "pub3" ]
            }
        });

    let queryParameters = {
        operation: 'FSale'
    }


    const publications = await PublicationService.getPublications(queryParameters);

    expect(publications.data.answer.publications).toEqual([ "pub1", "pub2", "pub3" ]); // works fine
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); //This fails
})
```

I was actually trying to use the approach [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716844/how-do-you-verify-that-a-request-was-made-with-axios-mock-adapter?rq=1).

Update: Here's the code for getPublications

```
async function _getPublications(queryParameters){
  return await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `${PUBLICATIONS_PATH}/publications`,
      cancelToken: CancelTokenService.getSource().token,
      params: queryParameters,
      headers: {
        authorization: LocalStorageService.getAuthorization(),
        'Accept': ResourcesVersions.PUBLICATION
      }
  }).then(function (response){ return response }).catch(function (error){ return (axios.isCancel(error) ? error : error.response) })
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code of `getPublications` please ?

Comment: Just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test code you provided you are spying on axios `get` method, but in the `getPublications` method you are not calling that method. Instead, you are calling the `axios` method directly.

As spying the `axios` default method is not easy, I would suggest to change the code in `getPublications` to use the `get` method:

```
async function _getPublications(queryParameters){
  return await axios.get(`${PUBLICATIONS_PATH}/publications`, {
      cancelToken: CancelTokenService.getSource().token,
      params: queryParameters,
      headers: {
        authorization: LocalStorageService.getAuthorization(),
        'Accept': ResourcesVersions.PUBLICATION
      }
  }).then(function (response){ return response }).catch(function (error){ return (axios.isCancel(error) ? error : error.response) })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter#history feature to check what actual calls have been made and assert on URLs, headers, methods and what-else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to use `jest.spy` on my test but I think you could try something like:

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');
...

it('gets publications', async() => {

    const get = axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(yourMockedData)

    let queryParameters = {
        operation: 'FSale'
    }


    const publications = await PublicationService.getPublications(queryParameters);

    expect(publications.data.answer.publications).toEqual([ "pub1", "pub2", "pub3" ]); // works fine
    expect(get).toHaveBeenCalled(); //This fails
})
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I'm looking to keep using axios-mock-adapter.

Comment: Alright, just wondering if you have tried using a promise instead of async await

Comment: @Stackoverflowed on the other side, I'd rather make a separate test for PublicationService mocking axios and then using a mocked response for PublicationService in this test. The idea is not to have dependencies.